# How to get values from a ResultSet generically?

Tags: java, generics, jdbc, resultset

I need to retrieve the values from a `ResultSet` to use them via reflexion to invoke a constructor. 
I was trying with Class.cast(Object), but I always get an `InvalidCastException`.

This is what I have:

```
    Object[] args = new Object[count];
    Class<?>[] arr = co.getParameterTypes(); 
    for(i = 0; i<args.length; i++){

        args[i] = arr[i].cast(rs.getObject(i+1));
    }

    Object t;

    try {
        t = co.newInstance(args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    }

    return (T)t;
```

co is the constructor, and rs is the `ResultSet` I already have.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? The table, the SQL select and/or `co`'s class?

Comment: The context of this is to create a generic converter for a Dynamic Proxy. This converter will convert a ResultSet into a Domain Entity he knows. We are currently trying this with Northwind and the table could be any one in that DB. The constructor class again can be any domain entity for Northwind in our app.

Comment: So `co` can be effectively of any class, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that´s it. Any Class we created to Model Northwind

Comment: What happens if you do it without the cast?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can get this to work, there's a long-term maintenance nightmare that the order of the arguments in the Object's constructor may not match the order of the columns in the `ResultSet` (the table in the RDB).  e.g., if your `Person` object has a constructor taking a firstName, lastName, the order of the columns in the DB Table may not match.  It could be LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, or even FIRST_NAME, SOME_COLUMN_YOU_DONT_CARE_ABOUT, LAST_NAME.

In code I have seen to handle this issue more generically, they use reflection upon the domain object (e.g. Person) to get the property names (in my case, they looked at setters, not constructors, YMMV), then try to match them to the `ResultSet` column names, using `ResultSet.getMetaData()`.

Comment: We pretty much covered that part the only real issue here now is to actualy be able to get "things" from the ResultSet via the getObject method and then pass this objects to the constructor as arguments. Since the SQL type system is diferent from the one in Java, we will always have a CastException. How can we do this, without using the getString, getInt, getDouble etc..... methods of the ResultSet.

Comment: I think you need to have an icky series of if/else statements (or a switch) mapping between the Java types and the SQL types getInt, getDouble etc...  But since it's all in one central place it will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: You could also write your own enum corresponding to java.sql.Types, which allows this to be done is a fairly clean O-O way.  Note to Oracle for Java 9: Please make an enum version of java.sql.Types!